# nodejs' req.hostname as mongo doc index. bad practice?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I'm building a nodejs app I would like to make available under various settings by my customers. I want my customers to build their websites on top of my app, so: - the app can be configured in a way that domains "A.com" and "B.com" use the configuration "X" of the app, while "C.com" uses "Y", etc. - I'm thinking about using kubernetes and dockers containers to isolate version "X", "Y" etc. of my app - I'm also thinking about using nginx for reverse-proxy

Each domain will have its distinct documents in a mongodb collection. Because I need a way to retrieve the right data, I'm giving each domain a unique token matching their documents. All the tokens are also saved in mongodb and will be retrieved on my (nodejs) server's start or updated on the fly. The tokens will be saved on a "app.locals" variable: - I'm thinking about having a middleware that will grap the domain from every request (req.hostname) and get the corresponding token

```
// set locals
app.locals.domainTokens = {};
```

after retrieving and assigning the tokens, "domainTokens" will look like:

```
app.locals.domainToken = {
    "Acom" : "token_1",
    "Bcom" " "token_2"   // and so on
}

// the middleware
function grabToken(req, res, next) {
    var tokens = app.locals.domainToken,
        host = req.hostname;
    req.params.token = host ? tokens[host] : undefined;
    next();
}
```

When new customers register, tokens will be assigned on the fly for their domain (containers talk to each other, right?).

So basically, when a request is made for "A.com", my middleware sets the "token" so that the mongodb documents related to "A.com" can be found and sent back to client running version "X" of my app (nginx).

What do you think about this approach ? is it unsafe? a bad practice? do you have a better suggestion to implement it? Am I better off using one container per domain ? (I would have to monitor hundreds of nodejs instances instead of 3 or 4)

Also, is it possible to dynamically configure a Nginx server?